# Как нарисовать сектор круга в CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, canvas

Нарисовать круг с чистым CSS легко.

```
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: green;
}
```

А как нарисовать сектор? Учитывая угол `X - [0-360]`, я хочу нарисовать сектор `X` градусов. Могу ли я сделать это с помощью чистого `CSS`?

Для примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это поможет кому-то, вот пример функции `JQuery`, которая получает процент и рисует сектор.

```js
$(function drawSector() {
  var activeBorder = $("#activeBorder");
  var prec = activeBorder.children().children().text();
  if (prec > 100)
    prec = 100;
  var deg = prec * 3.6;
  if (deg <= 180) {
    activeBorder.css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(' + (90 + deg) + 'deg, transparent 50%, #A2ECFB 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, #A2ECFB 50%, transparent 50%)');
  } else {
    activeBorder.css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(' + (deg - 90) + 'deg, transparent 50%, #39B4CC 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, #A2ECFB 50%, transparent 50%)');
  }

  var startDeg = $("#startDeg").attr("class");
  activeBorder.css('transform', 'rotate(' + startDeg + 'deg)');
  $("#circle").css('transform', 'rotate(' + (-startDeg) + 'deg)');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.prec {
  top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.prec:after {
  content: '%';
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #E6F4F7;
}

.active-border {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #39B4CC;
  background-image: linear-gradient(91deg, transparent 50%, #A2ECFB 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, #A2ECFB 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="activeBorder" class="active-border">
    <div id="circle" class="circle">
      <span class="prec">66</span>
      <span id="startDeg" class="90"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to draw a circle sector in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21205652/7394871) от участника  [@Itay Gal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034637/itay-gal).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/21205652/7394871

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Решение с толстой границей и `stroke-dasharray`.*

В `svg` обводка элемента распространяется по обе стороны от его реальной границы:

```css
.example{
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-opacity: .25;
  stroke-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <circle class="example" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" />
</svg>
```

Таким образом можно нарисовать круг, используя только обводку. Для этого нужно указать радиус в 2 раза меньше, чем необходимый радиус сектора, и такую же толщину обводки. А уже долю видимой границы (визуально - сектор круга) легко регулировать через свойство [stroke-dasharray](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-fill-and-stroke/#stroke-dasharray):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input',function(){
  var sector = document.querySelector('.sector');
  
  //длина окружности по реальной границе. 
  var strokeLength = sector.getTotalLength();
  
  //Её можно рассчитать и через 2r
  //var strokeLength = 2*Math.PI*sector.getAttribute('r');
  
  var part = this.value, 
      result = strokeLength/100*part;
      
  sector.style.strokeDasharray = result + ',' + strokeLength;
})
```

```css
.border{
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.sector{
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 50px;
}
label,
span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <circle class="sector" r="25" cx="50" cy="50" />
  <circle class="border" r="49.5" cx="50" cy="50" />
</svg>
<label>
  <span>Значение (%)</span>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0">
</label>
```

Современное решение на `css` с [коническим градиентом](https://caniuse.com/css-conic-gradients):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input',function(){
  var chart = document.querySelector('.pie-chart');      
  chart.style.setProperty('--value',this.value + '%');
})
```

```css
.pie-chart{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  --value: 30%;
  background: conic-gradient(green var(--value), transparent 0);
}
label,
span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pie-chart"></div>
<label>
  <span>Значение (%)</span>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="30">
</label>
```

Answer (score 18):

### CSS и несколько фоновых градиентов

Вместо того, чтобы пытаться нарисовать зеленую часть, вы могли бы нарисовать белые части:

```
pie {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}

.ten {
    background-image:
        /* 10% = 126deg = 90 + ( 360 * .1 ) */
        linear-gradient(126deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

Ниже полный код:

```css
pie {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid green;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}

.ten {
  background-image: linear-gradient(126deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.twentyfive {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.fifty {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}


/* Slices greater than 50% require first gradient
   to be transparent -> green */

.seventyfive {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, green 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.onehundred {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<pie class="ten"></pie>
<pie class="twentyfive"></pie>
<pie class="fifty"></pie>
<pie class="seventyfive"></pie>
<pie class="onehundred"></pie>
```

### Scalable Vector Graphics

В этом варианте, вы можете добиться аналогичного эффекта с помощью элементов SVG `<circle>` и `<path>`

Рассмотрим следующее:

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="110"></circle>
  <path d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 190,35 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Вышеприведенной код достаточно прямолинейнен. У нас есть элемент, содержащий круг и путь.
Центр окружности - `115x115` (создание элемента SVG `230x230`). Круг имеет радиус `110`, что делает его диаметр `220` (оставляя границу `5` с обоих сторон).

Затем мы добавляем элемент `<path>`, который является самой сложной частью этого примера. Этот элемент имеет один атрибут, который определяет, где и как нарисован путь. Он начинается со следующего значения:

`M115,115`

Это указывает путь к началу в центре вышеупомянутого круга. Затем мы нарисуем линию из этого места в другое место:

`L115,5`

Это рисует вертикальную линию от центра круга до вершины элемента (ну, пять пикселей сверху). Именно в этот момент все становится немного сложнее, но все же очень понятно.

Теперь мы нарисуем дугу из нашего текущего местоположения (115,5):

`A110,110 1 0,1 190,35 z`

Это создает нашу дугу и дает ей радиус, соответствующий нашему кругу (110). Два значения представляют `x-радиус` и `y-радиус`, и оба они равны, так как мы имеем дело с кругом. Следующий набор важных чисел - последний, `190,35`. Это говорит дуге, где нужно остановиться.

Что касается остальной информации `(1 0,1 и z)`, то они контролируют кривизну, направление и вывод самой дуги. Вы можете узнать больше о них, обратившись к любой [ссылке в Интернете](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900#comm_a) по SVG.

Чтобы выполнить `slice` другого размера, просто измените значение `190,35`, чтобы отразить больший или меньший набор координат. Вы можете обнаружить, что вам нужно создать вторую дугу, если вы хотите охватить более `180` градусов.

Если вы хотите определить координаты `x` и `y` с помощью угла, вы можете использовать следующие уравнения:

```
x = cx + r * cos(a)
y = cy + r * sin(a)
```

В приведенном выше примере при значении угла -`76` это будет:

```
x = 115 + 110 * cos(76)
y = 115 + 110 * sin(76)
```

Полученные значения : `205.676,177.272`

Так же легко  вы можете создать следующее:

```css
circle {
  fill: #f1f1f1;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 5;
}

path {
  fill: green;
}

svg.pie {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="pie">
  <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="110"></circle>
  <path d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 190,35 z">
  </path>
</svg>

<svg class="pie">
  <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="110"></circle>
  <path d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 225,115 z">
  </path>
</svg>

<svg class="pie">
  <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="110"></circle>
  <path d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 115,225 A110,110 1 0,1 35,190 z">
  </path>
</svg>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/tYaVW/

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to draw a circle sector in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21206274/7394871) от участника  [@Sampson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54680/sampson).</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Вариант с canvas

```js
function draw(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(125,125);
  ctx.lineTo(250,0);
  ctx.lineTo(250,120);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fill();
}
draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="circle" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 8):

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, transparent 50%, #fff 0);
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.circle::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: rotate(70deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Больше информации здесь: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/

Answer (score 7):

СSS Вариант, без градиентов, но с псевдо элементами в виде прямоугольников:

Сектора в двух кругах по центру появляются при наведении, для последнего это тоже возможно, но анимация там будет сложнее =)

```css
sector.a30:before {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
sector.a60:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
sector.a160:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(-160deg);
}
sector.a220:after {
  transform: rotate(-220deg);
}

sector {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

sector:before {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

sector:after {
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

sector:before, sector:after {
  transition:300ms;
  background-color: white;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
}

sector.a220:before, sector.a220:after {
  background-color: green;
}
sector.a220 {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<sector class="a30"></sector>
<sector class="a60"></sector>
<sector class="a160"></sector>
<sector class="a220"></sector>
```