# Как реализовать Анимацию выделения сектора окружности цветом от 0 до 360 градусов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Образно, процесс можно проиллюстрировать на примере стрелочных часов: одна стрелка неподвижна, другая двигается до определённого значения и пространство между ними заполняется цветом (стрелок при этом нет, это просто образная визуализация границ).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821164/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%B2-css   Выбирайте любой ответ и анимируйте.

Comment: Анимаций вообще обнаглел - постоянно требует у других что-то ему реализовать...

Comment: Задач больше, чем заданных вопросов. Что-то решил сам. Я только учусь и нужны примеры.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### CSS решение

Все стили перенес в `css` и анимация сделана с помощью правил `css`

```css
.container {
width:25%;
height:25%
}
#crc {
fill:none;
stroke:green;
stroke-width:100;
stroke-dashoffset:314;
stroke-dasharray:314;
animation: draw 10s ease-out infinite forwards;
}
@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<circle id="crc" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)" cx="100" cy="100" r="45" /> 
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="8" fill="gold" />
</svg> 
</div>
```

**Приложение полностью адаптивно, так же как вариант решения `SVG`**

Работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме `IE`, который не понимает анимацию по определению.

Comment: Всё, надо изучить SVG. Спасибо. Я пробовал анимировать linear-gradient, но я подозреваю, что его нельзя анимировать.

Comment: Поставил :) Просто ходил на сайт SVG у вас в профиле.

Answer (score 4):

### SVG решение

Используется техника с изменением атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения до нуля. Поэтому линия будет рисоваться от нуля до полной длины.

Возьмем окружность с радиусом `r="50px"` поэтому длина окружности будет равна `2*50*3.14=314`

максимальные значения -`stroke-dashoffset="314"` `stroke-dasharray="314"`

*Первый пример будем анимировать рисование окружности:*

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<circle transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" stroke-dashoffset="314" stroke-dasharray="314" >
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="314;0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
</circle>
</svg>
```

Чтобы рисовать сектор сделаем ширину строки окружности равной радиусу, умноженному на `2`, так как строка рисуется равномерно по обе стороны от линии.

Итого будет `stroke-width="100"`

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<circle transform="rotate(-90 100 100)" cx="100" cy="100" r="45" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="100" stroke-dashoffset="314" stroke-dasharray="314" > 
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="314;0" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"    />
</circle>
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="8" fill="gold" stroke="grey" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать это после того, как завершу эксперименты с другим вариантом.

Comment: @fromillia а какой вам другой вариант нужен? Могу сделать на CSS

Comment: Я сейчас пытаюсь анимировать это дело посредством анимации CSS. Вот сейчас ищу ответ на вопрос, можно ли достичь плавности в переходах между ключевыми кадрами.

Comment: Тема SVG конечно же меня интересует и вы хорошо всё объясняете, просто я как-то на автопилоте пытаюсь не терять времени и реализовать задачу с помощью тех инструментов, которые мне как-то знакомы. Просто тему SVG я ещё не затронул: хотелось бы изучить тему полноценно, от основ до анимации, поэтому сначала попытался использовать css-анимацию :)

Comment: @fromillia вот теперь можно сравнить два варианта и понять, что SVG анимация совсем не страшна в изучении :)