# Как мне сделать круглый бордер, с длиной 50%, 70% и 90%

Tags: css

На картинке есть 3 цифры с бордером, а на поверхности бордера есть еще один с цветом желтым, но не понимаю как сделать круглый бордер не с 100% длины.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полагаю что этих (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821164/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%B2-css) идей будет достаточно....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наложить два блока с полубордером, или псевдоэлементы. Так легко сделать дугу от 25% окружности, если меньше - подход менять придется.

```css
.chart {
  line-height: 44px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.chart:before,
.chart:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 3px 3px 3px 0;
  border-style: solid solid solid none;
  border-color: red;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
  transform-origin: 0 25px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 22px;
}

.chart[percent="70"]:after {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.chart[percent="90"]:after {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" percent="50">2</div>
<div class="chart" percent="70">3</div>
<div class="chart" percent="90">4</div>
```

Comment: спасибо , но что то тяжело розобрать все самому в бордерах)

Comment: грубо говоря - накладываются друг на друга два одинаковых элемента, которые сделаны в виде полукругов (верхний, правый и левый бордеры есть, а радиусы закругления обоих правых углов равны высоте элемента). А потом один из них поворачивается на нужный угол, например, надо вам 70% показать - значит, 360 градусов * 0.7 = 252 градуса. Минус 180 (т.к. полкруга у вас уже есть) = 72. И вращается один из элементов на 72 градуса. Вращение надо сделать относительно середины левой стороны.